# How to load google map using jQuery on the anchor click

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to load google map on the anchor click. Below are the details.

I have **index.aspx** page where I have got one anchor tag and a div "divLoadMap"

```
<a class="loadMap" href="map.aspx">Load Map</a>
<div id="divLoadMap">
</div>
```

And I have **map.aspx** which have maps details. Below is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="_LANGUAGE" xml:lang="_LANGUAGE">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Simple Jquery CSS Tabs and V3 Google Maps</title>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="/common/js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

      function initialize() 
        {     
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(25.294371, 55.332642);     
            var myOptions = {       zoom: 8,       center: latlng,       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP     };     
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),         myOptions);


            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                title: 'Dubai'
            });
            var contentString = 'Dubai';

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString,
                maxWidth: 50
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });

        }  

     initialize(); 

    });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
   <form id="mapform" >
   <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
   </div>
   </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want load this map on the click of anchor tag which is present on **index.aspx**.

Please suggest!! would appreciate if can get code sample for above problem.

Comment: Your question is unclear - if you click the anchor, you will be taken to map.aspx, which will load in the map.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: On the anchor it will open the map.aspx in a overlay window i.e on the same page a lightbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought below approach.

1. Declare a div with id = 'GoogleMapContainer'
2. Make it by default display: none.
3. inside this div, declare iframe and assign src property of this iframe to index.aspx page.
4. Now onclick of anchor tag call a javascript function, which internally will call query modal dialog for above declared div.
5. this will result into a popup window which contain google map.

7.

```
<div id="GoogleMapContainer" title="Google Map Container" style="display: none;">
        <iframe id="frameGoogleMapContainer" height="100%" width="100%" src="index.aspx"
            frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
</div>
```

1. Call javascript function on click of anchor tag. and in that javascript function write this code:

   $jq ("#GoogleMapContainer").dialog({
           modal: true,
           width: 750,
           title: 'Google Map',
           resizable: false,
           open: function(type, data) {
               $jq(this).parent().appendTo("form");
           }
       });

Please suggest whether is it right approach or I need to do some modifications!!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a lightbox plugin that handles iframes. [Pirobox](http://www.pirolab.it/pirobox/) is one example.

this plugin uses the rel attribute to set the lightbox options.  In your case you would use iframe-*width-height* parameters.  Your code will look something like this:

```
//using 'full' for width and height will make the lightbox fullscreen 
//or you can specify a width and height in pixels.
<a href="map.aspx" rel="iframe-full-full" class="pirobox_gall1" >Load Map</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this way....

> ```
>       function initialize() 
>         {     
>             var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(25.294371, 55.332642);     
>             var myOptions = {       zoom: 8,       center: latlng,       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP     };     
>             var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
> ```
>
> myOptions);
>
> ```
>             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
>                 position: latlng,
>                 map: map,
>                 title: 'Dubai'
>             });
>             var contentString = 'Dubai';
>
>             var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
>                 content: contentString,
>                 maxWidth: 50
>             });
>             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
>               infowindow.open(map,marker);
>             });
>
>         }  
>
>     });
> ```

```
    </script>
```

Now just call this initialize() function on a anchor click or a button click.....

Comment: But what about the pop up window in which, I need to show the map and also I need the parameter to be passed from the anchor click as I might have lots of countries to show in map.